# How can I update an attribute created by a base class' mutable default argument, without modifying that argument?

Tags: python, dictionary, super

I've found a strange issue with subclassing and dictionary updates in new-style classes:

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71605, Apr 14 2009, 22:40:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
>>> class a(object):
...     def __init__(self, props={}):
...             self.props = props
...
>>> class b(a):
...     def __init__(self, val = None):
...             super(b, self).__init__()
...             self.props.update({'arg': val})
...
>>> class c(b):
...     def __init__(self, val):
...             super(c, self).__init__(val)
...
>>> b_inst = b(2)
>>> b_inst.props
{'arg': 2}
>>> c_inst = c(3)
>>> c_inst.props
{'arg': 3}
>>> b_inst.props
{'arg': 3}
>>>
```

In debug, in second call (`c(3)`) you can see that within `a` constructor `self.props` is already equal to `{'arg': 2}`, and when `b` constructor is called after that, it becomes `{'arg': 3}` for both objects!

also, the order of constructors calling  is:

```
  a, b    # for b(2)
  c, a, b # for c(3)
```

If you replace `self.props.update()` with `self.props = {'arg': val}` in `b` constructor, everything will be OK, and will act as expected

But I really need to *update* this property, not to replace it.

Comment: Is this an inheritance problem, or a "default parameter values are evaluated ONCE" problem?

Comment: Thank you, replacing with `{}` with `None` helped me.

Comment: Thank you, Hank, I've renamed the question so

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: It is funny, when you think that you've almost got this nice language, to find that the situations are thinking opposite.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`props` should not have a default value like that. Do this instead:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, props=None):
        if props is None:
            props = {}
        self.props = props
```

This is a common python ["gotcha"](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/).

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is in this line:

```
def __init__(self, props={}):
```

{} is an mutable type. And in python default argument values are only evaluated once. That means all your instances are sharing the same dictionary object!

To fix this change it to:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, props=None):
        if props is None:
            props = {}
        self.props = props
```

Comment: Don't do "if not props", a boolean false value can break that line

Comment: @Gorgapor, You are right is None is more accurate. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The short version: Do this:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self, props=None):
        self.props = props if props is not None else {}

class b(a):
    def __init__(self, val = None):
        super(b, self).__init__()
        self.props.update({'arg': val})

class c(b):
    def __init__(self, val):
    super(c, self).__init__(val)
```

The long version:

The function definition is evaluated exactly once, so every time you call it the same default argument is used. For this to work like you expected, the default arguments would have to be evaluated every time a function is called. But instead Python generates a function object once and adds the defaults to the object ( as `func_obj.func_defaults` )