# How to pass an arguments in class creation with object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I am trying to save the cookies for my selenium automation script in order to avoid login process for future automation.

This is the original script which works fine

```
class SeleniumDriver(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        # chromedriver path
        driver_path='chromedriver.exe',
        # pickle file path to store cookies
        cookies_file_path = 'cookies.pkl',
        # list of websites to reuse cookies with
        cookies_websites=["https://website.com"] # I would like to replace this website by an argument

    ):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.cookies_file_path = cookies_file_path
        self.cookies_websites = cookies_websites
        #PREVIOUS VERSION WITH NORMAL CHROME chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        #PREVIOUS VERSION WITH NORMAL CHROME self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        self.driver = uc.Chrome(
            executable_path=self.driver_path,
            options=chrome_options
        )
        try:
            # load cookies for given websites
            cookies = pickle.load(open(self.cookies_file_path, "rb"))
            for website in self.cookies_websites:
                self.driver.get(website)
                for cookie in cookies:
                    self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
                self.driver.refresh()
        except Exception as e:
            # it'll fail for the first time, when cookie file is not present
            logger.error(str(e))
            logger.error("ERROR : Error loading cookies")

    def save_cookies(self):
        # save cookies
        cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()
        pickle.dump(cookies, open(self.cookies_file_path, "wb"))

    def close_all(self):
        # close all open tabs
        if len(self.driver.window_handles) < 1:
            return
        for window_handle in self.driver.window_handles[:]:
            self.driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            self.driver.close()

    def quit(self):
        self.save_cookies()
        self.close_all()
        self.driver.quit()


selenium_object = SeleniumDriver()
driver = selenium_object.driver
```

You can see in the code during the creation of object, the url of website "https://website.com" is used to create the cookies for this website.

If tomorrow, I use my script for "https://anotherwebsite.com", I would need to pass hthe website as arguments like this for example:

```
class SeleniumDriver(object,website): # the variable website is passed as argument in class creation
    ....

website="https://anotherwebsite.com"
selenium_object = SeleniumDriver(website)
```

My problem is I alsways have this error output:

```
NameError: name 'website' is not defined
```

Here is full code which doesn't work:

```
class SeleniumDriver(object,website):
    def __init__(
        self,
        # chromedriver path
        driver_path='chromedriver.exe',
        # pickle file path to store cookies
        cookies_file_path = 'cookies.pkl',
        # list of websites to reuse cookies with
        cookies_websites=[website]

    ):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        self.cookies_file_path = cookies_file_path
        self.cookies_websites = cookies_websites
        #PREVIOUS VERSION WITH NORMAL CHROME chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
        #PREVIOUS VERSION WITH NORMAL CHROME self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        self.driver = uc.Chrome(
            executable_path=self.driver_path,
            options=chrome_options
        )
        try:
            # load cookies for given websites
            cookies = pickle.load(open(self.cookies_file_path, "rb"))
            for website in self.cookies_websites:
                self.driver.get(website)
                for cookie in cookies:
                    self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
                self.driver.refresh()
        except Exception as e:
            # it'll fail for the first time, when cookie file is not present
            logger.error(str(e))
            logger.error("ERROR : Error loading cookies")

    def save_cookies(self):
        # save cookies
        cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()
        pickle.dump(cookies, open(self.cookies_file_path, "wb"))

    def close_all(self):
        # close all open tabs
        if len(self.driver.window_handles) < 1:
            return
        for window_handle in self.driver.window_handles[:]:
            self.driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            self.driver.close()

    def quit(self):
        self.save_cookies()
        self.close_all()
        self.driver.quit()

website="https://mywebsite.com"
selenium_object = SeleniumDriver(website)
driver = selenium_object.driver
```

When I run this code, I get this error output:

```
 class SeleniumDriver(object,website):
NameError: name 'website' is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you trying to put `website` there? That `()` section is used for inheritance. It seems like you just want `SeleniumDriver(cookies_websites=[website])`. Also note, you should [never have mutable objects as default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367883/methods-default-parameter-values-are-evaluated-once).

Comment: Instead of showing the script that works, show the update that doesn't work. As an aside, in python 3, you don't need to explicitly inherit from `object`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to helo. Sorry, I added the part of code which doesn't work. I though it would be clear enough. I just edited my question by adding the complete code which doesn't work.